# Canadian SHipping is coming up free when I did not set it up that way?

Tags: magento-1.9, free-shipping, usps

For some reason all our Caniadian sales are getting free shipping USPS priority Mail when we did not set this up? They get a charge for Express Mail but Priority mail shows $0. What could cause this?

Answer (score 1):

Did you apply SUPEE-6237 yet? This fixes some things with the USPS API on the Magento end. (specifically how it calls Canadian shipping rates)

https://www.magentocommerce.com/download